# How can I convert a string to a float with Perl?

Tags: perl, floating-point, string-parsing

Is there any function like `int()` which can convert a string to float value?
I'm currently using the following code:

```
$input=int(substr($line,1,index($line,",")-1));
```

I need to convert the string returned by `substr` to float.

Comment: can you give an example of how `$line` is generated?

Comment: $line is read from a log file.
 open (fHandle,"+<",$path) or die "$!";
foreach $line(<fHandle>)
  { $input=int(substr($line,1,index($line,",")-1));
                }
This is the complete code.

Comment: Can we have an example line from your file please so we can suggest better ways to extract the number.

Comment: sure.Here you go - 
[1258200601.016453, 'unknown', 'error', 'unknown Exception ', 110012]

Comment: Please improve your question with any clarifications rather than hiding those in the comments.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Just use it. In Perl, a string that looks like a number IS a number.

Now, if you want to be sure that the thing is a number *before* using it then there's a utility method in `Scalar::Util` that does it:

```
use Scalar::Util qw/looks_like_number/;

$input=substr($line,1,index($line,",")-1);

if (looks_like_number($input)) {
    $input += 1; # use it as a number!
}
```

Based on the sample input you left in the comments, a more robust method of extracting the number is:

```
$line =~ /([^\[\],]+)/; # <-- match anything not square brackets or commas
$input = $1;            # <-- extract match
```

Comment: When I use the substr as is, I get the following error:
Argument "1258200601.5027449," isn't numeric in int at test.pl

Comment: If that really is the error then your number has a comma in it which makes it not a number.

Comment: Edit: removed int() because you wanted float... @fixxxer: sorry I copy/pasted from your example.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know what your data looks like, but you do realize that the third argument to [substr](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/substr.html) is a length, not a position, right? Also, the first position is 0. I suspect you aren't getting the data you think you are getting, and it mostly accidently works because you are starting at the beginning of the string and are only off by one.

Comment: The data starts with a "[".so it is wise that we start with 0 and not 1 as the second argument to substr.Ofcourse, the third one has to be a number.What in the code, makes you think that we overlooked that?

Comment: The index() makes me think you overlooked that, and the fact that you aren't extracting something that Perl thinks is a number. Show us a complete example with input data so we don't have to guess.