# How to convert a string to a number (float) in Perl

Tags: perl

How do I convert a string to number in Perl?

Example:

```
$str = '10.0500000';
$number = $str * 1;  # 10.05
```

Is there another standard way to get 10.05 from '10.0500000' instead of multiplying with one?

Comment: Did you have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2019178/how-can-i-convert-a-string-to-a-float-with-perl?

Comment: @Jessada . it's not useful . It didn't talk about how to convert.

Comment: @Hindol int() will give integer value ...int(10.05000) = 10

Comment: What is wrong with 10.0500000 as a number? it is the same as 10.05 for all numeric uses it inly differs if used as a string

Answer (score 10, accepted):

edit 2020: Answer is wrong, see comment below. I am not permitted to delete an accepted answer.

---

I am answering the literal question. Perhaps you want to [format the number](http://p3rl.org/sprintf) for display.

Both expressions

```
sprintf '%.2f', '10.0500000'
sprintf '%.2f', 10.0500000
```

return the string `10.05`.

Comment: I don’t see how this answers the question. The question asks how to convert string to float, not the other way around.

Comment: You are correct, I screwed up. Will delete later.

Answer (score 9):

In Perl, scalars are not typed. Instead, operators are. So when you do `$a . "1"` you use `$a` as a string, and when you do `$a + 1` you use `$a` as a number. Perl will do its best to figure out what a scalar means for a given operation. So for most cases, "converting" is done implicitly for you.

If you need to verify that your string can indeed be converted, use regular expressions.

Here is one discourse on how to do that: http://www.regular-expressions.info/floatingpoint.html

Comment: Detecting a number with regex is a Perl FAQ: [How do I determine whether a scalar is a number/whole/integer/float?](http://learn.perl.org/faq/perlfaq4.html#How-do-I-determine-whether-a-scalar-is-a-number-whole-integer-float-)

Comment: @daxim: Ah, thank you. I knew there had to be a better source :)

Answer (score 7):

Well, you could add 0 as well :-)

You should not care too much about the internal representation of a scalar in Perl, unless you're doing some weird things (and please tell us if you are). Whatever looks like a number is a number.

Or do you need to check if the string is a "real" number? Well, actually, any string is. There's a
nice article [***Is it a Number***](http://web.archive.org/web/20171023025605/http://www.perl.com/doc/FMTEYEWTK/is_numeric.html)
on this topic. That link is to the *Wayback Machine* because the original has been deleted from `perl.com`.

Comment: The link is broken (404).

Comment: A use case for this is ensuring your JSON serialization results in a number rather than a string.

Answer (score 4):

`0+` is a bit more idiomatic. It's usually used to distinguish the components of dualvars.

```
$ perl -E'
   system({ "nonexistant" } "nonexistant");
   say 0+$!, ": ", $!;
'
2: No such file or directory
```

It looks weird because it's not something you normally have to do. A number is a number, whether it's stored internally as a PV, IV, UV or NV. Forcing it to be stored as a NV (float) shouldn't be necessary, and it usually indicative of buggy design elsewhere.